# How to specify Message Driven Bean dependencies in JBOSS 7 EJB 3?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have two message driven beans on which I need to specify a dependency. The dependency is a WEB app. So, basically I need to say "Halt the deployment of Message Driven Beans until the WEB app has fully deployed"? I could easily do this in JBOSS 5 by using `depends-on` element but I'm unable to find a similar element in JBOSS 7 EJB 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *application.xml* configuration file, you can specify the order of the modules to be deployed by the server. Below is the sample configuration for deployment, modify it accordingly.

```
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order> 
     <display-name>DeploymentConfig</display-name> 
          <module> 
         <web> 
             <web-uri>WebApp.war</web-uri> 
             <context-root>WebApp-war</context-root> 
         </web> 
     </module> 
     <module> 
         <ejb>EJBApp.jar</ejb> 
     </module> 
     <module> 
         <ejb>AppEAR.jar</ejb> 
     </module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for - [Classloading in AS 7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7). It describes how to set dependencies on other deployed modules and / or AS internal modules as well.